# How to decrease execution time for SVM

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am currently working on a dataset with 20 features and 400K rows. I'm using e1071 library for multi class classification using SVM. I have this code and it is taking about 2 days to get me the results. Is there a way I can reduce the time complexity using the same library? If not what other library or options should I consider preferably in R?

```
svm.model <- svm(y ~., data = traindata, gamma = 0.01, cost = 10, kernel= "radial")
```

Comment: I would try sub sampling maybe 1000-10000 rows and seeing what performance you get with a smaller number of samples - this may be enough information to get a decent model. Try different kernels as well.

Comment: Yes, I did try that. But the error difference is significant when taking sample of size 40K in comparison with the entire data.

Comment: are you doing training/testing, cross fold validation, etc?

Comment: Yes, 50% of the data for training 25% for testing and validation both.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest try dimensionality reduction(with PCA for example) to reduce the number of features, that would give a performance boost.